# Split character string by forward slash or nothing

Tags: r, regex, split

I want to split this vector

```
c("CC", "C/C")
```

to

```
[[1]]
[1] "C" "C"

[[2]]
[1] "C" "C"
```

My final data should look like:

```
c("C_C", "C_C")
```

Thus, I need some `regex`, but don't found how to solve the "non-space" part:

```
strsplit(c("CC", "C/C"),"|/")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `sub` (or `gsub` if it occurs more than once in your string) to directly replace either nothing or a forward slash with an underscore (capturing one character words around):

```
sub("(\\w)(|/)(\\w)", "\\1_\\3", c("CC", "C/C"))
#[1] "C_C" "C_C"
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use

```
lapply(strsplit(v1, "/|"), function(x) x[nzchar(x)])
```

---

Or use a regex lookaround

```
strsplit(v1, "(?<=[^/])(/|)", perl = TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "C" "C"

#[[2]]
#[1] "C" "C"
```

---

If the final output should be a vector, then

```
gsub("(?<=[^/])(/|)(?=[^/])", "_", v1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "C_C" "C_C"
```

Answer (score 5):

We can split the string at every character, omit the "/" and `paste` them together.

```
sapply(strsplit(x, ""), function(v) paste0(v[v!= "/"], collapse = "_"))

#[1] "C_C" "C_C"
```

**data**

```
x <- c("CC", "C/C")
```